# How do I show that $0$ is an additive identity using the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis

$(P1)$ If $a,b,$ and $c$ are any numbers, then

$a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c.$

$(P2)$ If $a$ is any number, then

$a+0=0+a=a$

$(P3)$ For every number $a$, there is a number $-a$ such that

$a+(-a)=(-a)+a=0$

assertion $(1)$: If a number $x$ satisfies

$a+x=a$

for any one number $a$, then $x=0$.

proof. If $a+x=a$,

then $(-a)+(a+x)=(-a)+a=0;$

hence $((-a)+a)+x=0$;

hence $0+x=0$;

hence $x=0$.

assertion $(2)$: If a number $x$ satisfies

$x+a=a$

for any one number $a$, then $x=0$.

proof. If $x+a=a$,

then $ (x+a) + (-a) = a + (-a)$;

hence $x + (a +(-a)) = 0$;

hence $x + 0 = 0$;

hence $x=0$.

Thus assertion $(1)$ iff $a+0=a$

and assertion $(2)$ iff $0+a=a$.

Does the above reasoning show that $0$ is *an* additive identity? I wanted to know why we would go about doing a uniqueness proof to show that the additive identity is $0$;that is, could we conceive that there is another distinct additive identity that does not satisfy assertion $(1)$ and assertion $(2)$?

Comment: $P2$ already _defines_ $0$ as an additive identity.

Comment: The **standard** proof of uniqueness is that if  $a$ is identity, then $0+a=0$ and if $0$ is an identity, then $0+a=a$, and hence if **both** are identities, then $0=a$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that ($P2$) which is the existence of an additive identity just meant in general that there exists an additive identity. And proving assertions $(1)$ and $(2)$ meant that $0$ is not just a "placeholder" for an additive identity.